# Convert logo from text semi-automatically

Tags: logo, effects

I am a software developer and new at logo design. I want to make a logo for my application based on its name, but I prefer to not use Adobe Illustrator or similar tools.

The ideal for me would be a site that I enter a word and choose from a list of decorations and let the site create a logo for me. Lets say like the old Word Art in Microsoft Word but a little more sophisticated. Do you have any ideas about?

Comment: What you are describing is decorating, not design. ;)

Comment: There is countless free software tools (both graphic design and text editing) that allow you to do this - [you will have to search for what suits your needs](https://www.google.fi/search?q=logo+software+free).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest this site: https://www.logaster.com/

They are the best option along these lines I am aware of.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose someone should tell you that any logo you create by this process won't really be all that good in terms of quality, in the same way that me tweaking a WordPress template doesn't make a quality website. Sure it works, and doing it yourself is always the cheapest option, but at some point you might want to seriously consider investing in a graphic designer who can design something that's high-quality and well-tailored to your application's needs.

However, based on what you asked, take a look at [Photo-Lettering](http://www.photolettering.com/). Some are a bit over the top, but some could suit an identity really well and you'll get some high-quality lettering for less than ten dollars.

Answer (score 1):

[Logaster](https://www.logaster.com/) or [CoolText](http://cooltext.com) would be my recommendations.